# How to access Webservice in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I am new in android development, i need to get the XML file from the Webservice by using SOAP message. I have tried my level best to find out SOAP message parsing in Android but, i cannot find out exact solution for the SOAP message parsing.  Here i have attached my sample code to parse the SOAP message. Can you please help me to parse the SOAP message in Android? 
(Response comes in permission denied).

I tried source code given below:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE ,METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("username","d");
request.addProperty("password","d123");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet=true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);envelope.setAddAdornments(true);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
try 
  {
      httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
      SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
      String results = result.toString();
      tv.setText( ""+results);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
       tv.setText(e.getMessage());
   }

AndroidManifest.Xml file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: Is REST not an option, also make sure you do this in a background  thread separate to the main UI thread like I explained in another question I answered yesterday here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812281/android-emulator-crash-if-click-while-processing/8812798#8812798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `envelope.getResponse();` in your code, prabably that can be the reason that you are not getting the Response.

You can try,

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
String results = result.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks you, but response is same permission denied

Comment: Post the exception in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webServicePath);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    String soapRequestXML = getXMLAsString();
    soapRequestXML = prepareInputParam(soapRequestXML);

    StringEntity se;
    se = new StringEntity(soapRequestXML, HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
```